# 00936. 00000 - "missing expression"

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have written pl/sql function getEmpNums('3A,5B,6B') , This function will return string like this "EMP_NO IN ('3A','5B','6B')" . I want to use this function in where clause . like below

```
SELECT EMP_NO FROM EMP_CUST_VALUES  WHERE (select getEmpNums('3A,5B,6B') from dual)
```

when i call like below getting "ORA-00936: missing expression". how to call function in where clause like this

I tried

```
SELECT EMP_NO FROM EMP_CUST_VALUES  WHERE (select getEmpNums('3A,5B,6B') from dual)
```

Its not working when i give directly its working

```
SELECT EMP_NO FROM EMP_CUST_VALUES  WHERE (EMP_NO IN ('3A','5B','6B'))
```

Comment: If you try to read your SQL statement as a general sentence you'll find that it makes no sense: where what? There's some expression in the `where` clause but hod it is related to the other part of your query? How DBMS should guess? Apart from this Oracle requires a [condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-E9EC8434-CD48-4C01-B01B-85E5359D8DD7) in the `where` clause, because it has no `boolean` datatype before 23c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although function your wrote probably returns what you wanted, the principle you chose works in a limited number of cases (Oracle Forms, Reports, maybe somewhere else) where you can *substitute* function result with a bind variable.

Usually, you'd rather opt to return a **collection** and use it with a `table` function, either as a join or in a subquery. Here's an example.

Function first; I used built-in datatype:

```
SQL> create or replace function getempnums(par_str in varchar2)
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    select trim(regexp_substr(par_Str, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  7      bulk collect into retval
  8      from dual
  9      connect by level <= regexp_count(par_str, ',') + 1;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> select empno, ename from emp where rownum <= 5;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
```

What does function return? A collection:

```
SQL> select getempnums('7369,7499, 7521') from dual;

GETEMPNUMS('7369,7499,7521')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('7369', '7499', '7521')
```

How to use it: **table function**:

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename
  2  from emp e join table(getempnums('7369,7499, 7521')) t on t.column_value = e.empno;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
```

**Subquery:**

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.empno in (select * from table(getempnums('7369,7499, 7521')));

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank for my query . I am appending string after result like below

condition:= condition  || ' OR (seat_number BETWEEN '||''''||seat_numbers(1)||''''|| ' AND ' ||''''||seat_numbers(2)||''''||')';

finally i am returning string like this

result_query:=condition;

result_query is final string i am returning .
Could you please help how to return since your solution is returning  list . How to append

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a function, or an `IN` expression.

Instead, you can use the delimited list directly in the query and match on sub-strings (with the surrounding delimiters to match entire terms):

```sql
SELECT EMP_NO
FROM   EMP_CUST_VALUES
WHERE  ',' || '3A,5B,6B' || ',' LIKE '%,' || emp_no || ',%';
```

Comment: Thanks. But User enter data like this ''3A-5B,6A-9B'' . This time function will return like this 
((seat_number BETWEEN '3A' AND '5B') OR (seat_number BETWEEN '6A' AND '9B')).
How can i handle this senario

Comment: @satish Either write a function that changes `3A-5B,8A-9B` into `3A,3B,4A,4B,5A,5B,8A,8B,9A,9B` and then use `WHERE  ',' || your_function('3A-5B,8A-9B') || ',' LIKE '%,' || emp_no || ',%'` or write a pipelined function and check to see if the value is a member of the returned collection.

Comment: @satish If you have a new problem then ask a new question. We cannot debug code we have not seen (especially not in comments where the code does not display nicely).

Comment: Sorry to trouble . I will ask new question